# How to Parse A file to block in C++

Tags: c++, parsing, file, block

I am looking for an elegant way to parse a file to blocks and for each block create a new file , for example :

**original file:**

```
line 1
line 2
 line 3

line 4
 line 5
   line 6
line 7
```

**result:**

```
first file:
line 1

second file:
line 2
 line 3

third file:
line 4
 line 5
   line 6

fourth file:
line 7
```

thanks

Comment: Can you share your code that you have tried, mentioning the problem(s) that you are facing.

Comment: hey, i am having difficulties to write in C++ syntax. the algortithm is not a problem, i just want to avoid using C code and looking for a way to write it in C++ code with file iterators or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `scoped_ptr`s to change the output file when the input line does not begin with whitespace:

```
std::ifstream in("/your/input/file");
boost::scoped_ptr<std::ofstream> out(NULL)
int out_serial = 0;
std::string line;
while(std::getline(in, line))
{
    // test: first character non blank
    if(! line.empty() && (line.at(0) != ' ' && line.at(0) != '\t'))
    {
        std::ostringstream new_output_file;
        new_output_file << "/your/output/file/prefix_" << out_serial++;
        out.reset(new std::ofstream(new_output_file.str()));
    }
    if(out.get() != NULL) (*out) << line << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Leaking `ofstream`s left and right, otherwise not a bad approach.  Although I would suggest using just one `ofstream` and closing it, then opening a new file.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: What do you mean by leaking? `scoped_ptr<T>` will call the `delete` operator on nonnull `T*` pointers either on `scoped_ptr<T>::reset` or `scoped_ptr<T>::~scoped_ptr`.

Comment: As @Ben Voight, I would prefer closing and opening the file stream rather than dynamically allocating them. Anyway, if you are dynamically allocating the stream, then the ouput line should be `*out << line << std::endl;`. Without the dereference it won't compile. Also, to check for null you can just use the smart pointer in the condition as in `if (out) *out << ...`. There is a conversion to an *unspecified-bool-type* for that purpose. Anyway, a good skeleton to improve on. +1

Comment: @Benoit: Oh, `reset` is a deallocation function?  I hate functions with misleading names.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Actually, boost `scoped_ptr` and `shared_ptr` will take care of deallocating memory, the first one when destructed or reset, the second one when the last copy of the shared_ptr is reset or destructed.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you could use this algorithm:

> Count the number of spaces at the beginning of each line, if it's less than or equal to the number of spaces in the preceding non-empty line, open a new file.

What have you tried so far?

Comment: hey, i am having difficulties to write in C++ syntax. the algortithm is not a problem, i just want to avoid using C code and looking for a way to write it in C++ code with file iterators or something ...

Answer (score 0):

If your code is not properly intended or your blocks are only based on braces not spaces, you can use a stack(STL). Push on opening brace and Pop on closing brace. Open a new file each time the stack become empty